# Implement calling functionality in Android app

Tags: android, phone-call, telephony

I need to implement **calling functionality** in android app without using the **Intent.ACTION_CALL**........or **existing calling app**.....Pl share suggestions or an demo code

Comment: you have to use the default app for calling

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
public static void makeCall(Context context, String number) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(number)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        if (infos.size() > 0) {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please install a dialer app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Please add phone number to make a call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```